# How to make an Alertdialog with Multichoice items along with an EditText?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, multichoiceitems

I have a `AlertDialog` of **Multichoice** Items.I want to have an `EditText` beside each item. How do i achieve this?

```
 third_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EnterRecordActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setTitle("Select Contributor");
                mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listMembers, checkedMembers, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position, boolean isChecked) {

                    }
                });
                mDialog = mBuilder.create();
                mDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

**This is what i achieved till now with the following code**

[image: this is what i achieved till now with the following code]

[image: this is what i want]

**This is what i want. An edit text with each multichoice item**

Comment: You can create custom alert dialog

Comment: You can do this easily with recyclerview

Comment: @Shaon any proper examples of listView with checkBox and editText only.it would be really helpful.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create custom dialog like this:**

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (this).getLayoutInflater();
            //Your layout file name is custom_check_with_edt
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_check_with_edt, null);
           //get Id from custom view            
            EditText edtNote = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edt_notes);

            builder.setView(dialogView);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", (dialog, which) -> {
                   //YOUR LOGIC
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            Dialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom dialog by creating a class that extends the dialog class. Then you need to add the layout of the xml file. Follow this link [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

For multi choice and editext, use either listview or recycler view and define your item layout with checkboxes and edittext.

Comment: any proper examples of listView with checkBox and editText only.it would be really helpful.Thanks!!